# Setting data pin with NanodeUNIO

Tags: eeprom

I'm using a sketch that helps to reset Da Vinci XYZPrinter cartridge EEPROMs, and it's based on the NanodeUNIO library. It uses digital pin 7 for data. I want to use my TFT Touch Shield to set the extruder temperature, but the shield also makes use for digital pin 7. Being that the sheild is wired to use pin 7, it can't be changed. But any pin that can be used as a digital pin should be useable with NanodeUNIO (at least, that is my assumption), but I can't find where in NanodeUNIO it sets the data pin. Where is that pin set, and how can it be changed?

Comment: Did you try looking for a call to `pinMode()`?

Comment: It has a single call for pin 13, which is the LED to tell you when it's done. The pin is used both to red the contents of the EEPROM as well as to set it. Full code is here: https://github.com/voltivo/davinci_filament_reset_arduino/blob/master/xyz_dv_eprom.ino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xyz_dv_eprom.ino` uses low-level access rather than Arduino calls to manipulate PD7, most likely for speed reasons. Lines 96 through 104 (specifically 96, 97, 100, and 104) need to be modified in order to change both the port and the bit used.

[ATmegaXX8 pin mapping](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168)
[ATmegaXXX0 pin mapping](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping2560)
[ATmegaXXU4 pin mapping](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping32u4)